# Is there an easier way(pythonic) to write the following code?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
sigma_n = np.array([0.01, 0.1])

ls = np.array([0.1, 0.2])

for sigma_ni in sigma_n:
    for ls_i in ls:
        print("{},{}".format(sigma_ni, ls_i))
```

I was hoping to find out if there is any way I could print out the above in a pythonic way instead of 2 loops.

Comment: if you are printing, that's look good. You can use `itertools.product` so you can have just one loop. But that's essentially the same thing.

Comment: What is not Pythonic about this?

Comment: 2 for loops. If the arrays are large, it is certainly slow right?

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang. itertools.product helps for the next steps I will be working on.

Comment: Yes! Certainly helps @AkshaySehgal

Comment: @HarshvardhanUppaluru **but you must do those two loops** if you want to print everything. There's no way around this. Again, what isn't **pythonic** about this?

Comment: Reading through the comments - I have realized I am wrong. I am still at a learning stage and I thought there was an easier(I am using this term because I couldn't think of any other) way through loop through 2 arrays. That is why I used the term - pythonic

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools.product -

```
from itertools import product

items = product(sigma_n, ls)

for i in items:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this could be the way forward.

Comment: Do note that the object returned is a generator object and you will have to explicitly iterate or convert it to a list `list(items)` to work on its items.

Comment: @HarshvardhanUppaluru it is important to understand, this still effectively does two nested loops

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is correct.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal to be pedantic, it doesn't return a generator, but it is an iterator

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, are you sure? The documentation mentions -`product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

Comment: Yes, test it out yourself. `type(product(range(1))`

Comment: Ah yes i did that and it just returned the `itertools.product` class object. My question is, whether this class object is a generator or just an iterator. Let me check the source to figure it out.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal *generators are a type object*. If the type is not `generator` then it isn't a generator. All generators are iterators, not all iterators are generators. Generators have various additional methods, for example, `.close`, `.send` (since generators are also co-routines) and various attributes, like `.gi_running`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your printing [meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

`print(np.meshgrid(sigma_n, ls)`

```
[array([[0.01, 0.1 ],
       [0.01, 0.1 ]]), 
array([[0.1, 0.1],
       [0.2, 0.2]])]
```